# Searching through paginated API results in the Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to access the `/{object-id}/likes` endpoint (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes). I'm querying an object/page that has about 2,000 "likes" (I know this because I can manually inspect this on the Facebook website) so obviously I'm going to expect paginated results from the API - which I do get.

I also know from the "Using the Graph API" documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) that paginated results will either be time based, cursor based or offset based. When you call the `/{object-id}/likes` endpoint with a GET, and the results are paginated, the cursor part of the response looks something like this:

```
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MzA4MzQ3OTUyNTU0NjI2",
      "after": "MjE5MDQ3MjkxNDcyMTEw"
    }
  }
```

This would suggest to me that I should be able to add `?after=MjE5MDQ3MjkxNDcyMTEw` to the `/{object-id}/likes` call (i.e. `/{object-id}/likes?after=MjE5MDQ3MjkxNDcyMTEw` and the result should be the next paginated list of results - however, I get back the following:

```
{
    "data": [
    ]
}
```

Which isn't what I expected.

The other thing I would have expected is some links in the `paging` section of my original request with a `next` and `previous` link. I don't get this in the response either.

Is anyone able to shed some light on this?

Thanks!

edit: I've just realised that due to the ambiguous wording of the documentation for this endpoint, that it actually returns a list of pages that the *object* likes, not who likes that object. My question still stands though - I'd like to know what I need to do with the `before` and `after` cursor values.

Comment: there is no "next" parameter in the paging json, so there is no more data to get. the "next" parameter is an api call for the next batch of items.

Comment: What would those "items" be in this context?

Comment: well, the likes ;) - please add the exact api call, so we can test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results returned by calling **/{object_id}/likes** are list of pages liked by this page but not who liked this page.

Also **/{object_id}?fields=likes** gives you number of likes on the page that you manually inspected on facebook page.

Also in cursor based pagination , if you don't have next field inside paging along with cursors, it means there is no more data and there is no need to do any more paginated request

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If you check out the edit to the question, I acknowledge that I misunderstood the intent of the API call I was making, however I still don't know what the `before` and `after` parts of the API response are if they aren't pointing to paginated results. Any chance you could help clear up what they mean for me?

Comment: Cursor based pagination is implemented as usage of cursors before and after are required when there is previous and next links inside paging. When there are no next and previous there is no need to use them which implies there is no further data. But I'm not sure what before and after are pointing to when there is no previous and next links.